# For loop within an if statement - python

Tags: python-2.7

Please kindly let me know what I am doing wrong. What I want is if the users enters a number bigger than 10, it has to use a loop to output as many times its value, if not then it should print "sorry too small."

Herewith my code below:

```
num = int(raw_input("Enter a number:"))

for num in range (1,num):
    if num <=10:
       print "sorry, too small"
    else:
       print num*num
```

Comment: For loop should be inside else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put the for loop after the conditional. For example:

```
num = int(raw_input("Enter a number:"))

if num <=10:
   print "sorry, too small"
else:
   for num in range (1, num):
       print num*num
```

Comment: Thank you so much!